# Second ZfcRbac Assertion is not working | ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser, zfc-rbac

I have added below code inside `zfc_rbac.global.php`:

```
return [
'zfc_rbac' => [
   'assertion_map' => [
        'isAuthorizedToAddUser' => 'Application\Assertions\WhoCanAddUser',
        'isBranchOrOrgIdPresentIfNotAdmin' => 'Application\Assertions\BranchOrOrgIdPresentIfNotAdmin'
    ]
]]
```

And used it inside controller like below:

```
if (! $this->authorizationService->isGranted('isBranchOrOrgIdPresentIfNotAdmin')) {
    throw new UnauthorizedException('You are not authorized to add this aaa!');
}
```

but its throwing the exception even if I `return true` from assert method. But if I replace `isBranchOrOrgIdPresentIfNotAdmin` with `isAuthorizedToAddUser`, its working fine. What could be wrong here. Second assertion class `BranchOrOrgIdPresentIfNotAdmin` is just the replica of `WhoCanAddUser` class. Below is my `WhoCanAddUser` assertion class.

```
namespace Application\Assertions;

use ZfcRbac\Assertion\AssertionInterface;
use ZfcRbac\Service\AuthorizationService;
use ZfcRbac\Exception\UnauthorizedException;
use Zend\Session\Container;

class WhoCanAddUser implements AssertionInterface
{
    protected $notAuthorizedMessage = 'You are not authorized to add this user!';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->org_session = new Container('org');
    }

    /**
     * Check if this assertion is true
     *
     * @param AuthorizationService $authorization            
     * @param mixed $role            
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function assert(AuthorizationService $authorization, $role = null)
    {
        return true; //added this for testing if true is working and it worked, but second assertion is not working!
        switch($authorization->getIdentity()->getRole()->getName()){
            case 'admin':
                return true;
            break;
            case 'owner':
               if($role != 'member'){
                   throw new UnauthorizedException($this->notAuthorizedMessage);
               }
               return true;
            break;
            default:
                throw new UnauthorizedException($this->notAuthorizedMessage);
            break;
        }

        if($authorization->getIdentity()->getRole()->getName() != 'admin' && !$this->org_session->offsetExists('branchId')){
            throw new \Zend\Session\Exception\RuntimeException('You need to be connected to an Organisation's branch before you can add members. Contact your Organisation Owner.');
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something that second assertion is not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that, `isBranchOrOrgIdPresentIfNotAdmin` entry has to be inside permission table and have to assign that permission to lower level of role inside `hierarchicalrole_permission` table (that permission will be given to upper level of role as well in hierarchical way automatically) and it will work fine for all of them.